# Looking for common PyQGIS functions for QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqgis-3, qgis-3

I would like to rewrite some of my QGIS plugins to use more common functions used by all of my plugins.

There exist some older functions (GIS2) like

https://github.com/NathanW2/parfait

https://github.com/qgis/pyqgis_wrappers

and something newer like

https://github.com/boundlessgeo/lib-qgis-commons 
https://pypi.org/project/qgiscommons/
or
https://github.com/inasafe/inasafe/tree/master/safe/utilities

Are there any other known collections of PyQGIS3 common functions that can be used to do basic tasks like load vectorlayers, show comboboxes, create toolbar-actions or something like that without having to write these code-snippets everytime on your own?

Example:

If I want to lad a vectorlayer I can make use of the function load_layer from https://github.com/qgis/pyqgis_wrappers/blob/master/parfait/layer_wrappers.py

```
 def load_layer(filename, name = None):
    '''
    Tries to load a layer from the given file
    :param filename: the path to the file to load.
    :param name: the name to use for adding the layer to the current project.
    If not passed or None, it will use the filename basename
    '''
    name = name or os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]
    qgslayer = QgsVectorLayer(filename, name, 'ogr')
    if not qgslayer.isValid():
        qgslayer = QgsRasterLayer(filename, name)
        if not qgslayer.isValid():
            raise RuntimeError('Could not load layer: ' + unicode(filename))

return qgslayer
```

Comment: This is a very open ended question. I think there's a better chance to get an answer on the QGIS developer mailing list - if anything like that exists for QGIS3

Answer (score 2):

Great initiative!

As a brand-new PyQGIS user, I don't have (and don't know of) appropriately packaged collections. However, a number of "cookbooks" have code snippets that would be easy to package/fill in the gaps, perhaps:

1. https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html  (still 2.18, but hopefully updated soon to reflect 3.6 LTR?)
2. https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/index.html
3. http://www.green-forums.info/greenlib/geolibrary/Lawhead%20J/QGIS%20Python%20Programming%20Cookbook.%2020%20%2852%29/QGIS%20Python%20Programming%20Cookboo%20-%20Lawhead%20J.pdf (a commercial 2015 book, but seems to have been released for download)

Comment: The linked PyQGIS Developer Cookbook is already for QGIS 3 - and not for 2.18 as stated!